# sda1, sda2, what are these in my partition table?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning

I'm using Ubuntu on WMware.

My sda1 is in ext4 format, and I assume that it holds my OS and all other files?

What is sda2 and can I delete it and just put all my space into sda1? sda2 is in extended format.

What is the purpose of having this partition as opposed to having a single larger partition?

Comment: If you don't know what it is, and value your data *don't mess with it* Read up on partitioning, fstab, mountpoints and the file system hierarchy first. Considering you're talking about partitions and not mountpoints, and mountpoints tell you what is where, you are likely to end up horribly mangling your VM if you re-size partitions willynilly

Answer (score 0):

You can use lsblk to get further information on what each block device is used for.

e.g.

```
lsblk -f --output MODEL,SERIAL,SIZE,NAME,MOUNTPOINT,KNAME,TYPE,FSTYPE,UUID,LABEL
```

Answer (score 0):

Find out which partition is mounted on which folder, by typing

```
sudo cat /etc/fstab
```

and

```
mount
```

Then get a listing of your free disk space with

```
df -h
```

This will help you to see which partitions are where.

Most important: **Don't move data without knowing what you do.** You may cause startup failure on the next boot.